# Function appending true or false not work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I make a list:

```
nest_list = [['John like to play football'],['He likes Liverpool'],
             ['His favourite player is Salah'],['He would like to play as striker'],
             [],['James like to play F1'],['He likes Ferrari'],
             ['His favourite driver is Raikkonnen'],[],
             ['Stefani like to play basketball'],['She likes Chicago Bulls'],
             ['His favourite player is Micheal Jordan']]
```

I want to find where are empty list and iterate over them to get information about every person and store it as dataframe. For example:

```
Row 1: John Football Liverpool Salah Striker

Row 2: James F1 Ferrari Raikkonen Driver

Column: John James etc
```

To do so i tried function which save to list `True` when length of list is 0 and `False` otherwise.

Then i use itertools.compress to print items which selectors are True.

```
zip_nest_list = list(zip(range(len(nest_list)),nest_list))
import itertools

selectors = []
def is_empty(i):
    '''Create selectors list with True when empty list and false when not empty'''
    if len(zip_nest_list[i][1]) == 0:
        selectors.append(True)
    selectors.append(False)

for x in range(len(zip_nest_list)):
    is_empty(x)


result = itertools.compress(zip_nest_list,selectors)
#printing empty lists with number
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

The problem is that selectors have more elements then i expected (14 instead of 12). Between `True` and next `True` i have 4 times `False` but should be 3 times and one additional `False` after second `True`.

Why is that and how to fixed it? Is there any faster/better way to solve whole problem?

Answer (score 2):

you forgot the `else` clause in your `if` statement; `False` is appended to `selectors` in any case. it should be:

```
if len(zip_nest_list[i][1]) == 0:
    selectors.append(True)
else:
    selectors.append(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the missing `else:` - see [hiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54615282/7505395) - it always appends the `False` .

---

**[Zen of python: #3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - Simple is better than complex.**

You do not need [itertools.compress](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) at all:

> ```
> zip_nest_list = list(zip(range(len(nest_list)),nest_list))
> ```

is the same as:

```
zip_nest_list = list(enumerate(nest_list))
```

To get the indexes of the empty list you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
empties = [ x for x in enumerate(nest_list) if not x[1]] # empty list is Falsy

print( *empties, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
(4, [])
(8, [])
```

Doku:

- [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [Truthyness (value testing)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)